# Dichotomy... trichotomy... what about more than three cases?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a synonym or (concise phrase) for a dichotomy when there is an unspecified number of discrete groups?

The exact number is not known, so it is not suitable to write tetrachotomy, hexachotomy, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Got it! *[Polychotomy](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/263989?redirectedFrom=polychotomy&) - division into more than two parts or groups; esp. (Taxon.) the division of a taxonomic grouping into more than two subgroups; an instance of this.*

Comment: +1 You actually *jumped* on finding the word? Lol.